# Setting GitLab CI for NodeJS deployment in AWS Ubuntu Instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have an AWS Ubuntu instance which has GitLab CE configured. Now I want to configure GitLab CI to deploy my NodeJS app after each commit.I don't have any proper step by step solution for this.

My NodeJS app running in `/var/www/mean/my-app` on `http://myapp.mydomain.com` and the hosting is handled by Apache Proxy,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin anshad@mydomain.com
    ServerName gitlab.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.gitlab.mydomain.com

    ServerSignature Off

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    <Location />
       Require all granted
       ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080
       ProxyPassReverse http://gitlab.mydomain.com/
    </Location>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
    RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

    DocumentRoot /home/git/gitlab/public

    LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_forwarded.log common_forwarded
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_access.log combined env=!dontlog
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

And the app is bootstrapped using forever module

```
forever start app.js
```

The gitlab config check `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` gives,

```
Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 4.0.0 ? ... OK (4.0.0)
Repo base directory exists?
default... yes
Repo storage directories are symlinks?
default... no
Repo paths owned by git:git?
default... yes
Repo paths access is drwxrws---?
default... yes
hooks directories in repos are links: ... 
dev / my-app ... ok
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Access to /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Send ping to redis server: OK
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking Reply by email ...

Reply by email is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking Reply by email ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Git configured with autocrlf=input? ... yes
Database config exists? ... yes
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Uploads directory setup correctly? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
projects have namespace: ... 
dev / my-app ... yes
Redis version >= 2.8.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.1.0 ? ... yes (2.3.1)
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 2.7.3 ? ... yes (2.7.4)
Active users: 1

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

I used to login to the instance using SSH from my system,

```
ssh -i API-Key.pem ubuntu@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Created key using command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Runner config on `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "Production Runner"
  url = "http://gitlab.mydomain.com/ci"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "ubuntu"
    host = "ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX"
    identity_file = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
  [runners.cache]
```

Code on `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
test_async:   
 script:    
  - npm install
```

Because of my bad configuration, the runner gives error,

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.7.1 (f896af7)
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
Will be retried in 3s ...
```

My confusions are:

What should be the content of `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to deploy the committed code to the application location?

And how to configure a runner for this? If I have to use an `ssh` runner, what should be the configurations over there?

**Update:**

After providing `.pem` file as `identity_file`, getting the following error

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.7.1 (f896af7)
Using SSH executor...
Running on ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx via ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into 'builds/a92f1b91/0/dev/my-app'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab.mydomain.com/dev/my-app.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
ERROR: Build failed: Process exited with: 1. Reason was:  ()
```

Now there is a problem, git clone with http not working but ssh cloning works.

**Note:** Both gitlab and build environment are same host (same aws instance)

[Bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24388) reported in GitLab as well (http clone issue).

Comment: We currently have Gitlab and Gitlab CI up and working just fine in AWS, its pretty standard.  That said, although you provided a wealth of Gitlab configuration steps, you didn't provide any information on your VPC, Security Group, Subnet, NACL or any other AWS networking settings.  Have you confirmed baseline connectivity over port 80 or 443?  It sounds like you have three systems in play here, Gitlab, Gitlab CI box, and your App box.  There are connectivity concerns betwixt each of them.

Comment: @NickSharp in my VPC security group, I have inbound and outbound allowed from anywhere.

Comment: As I read .. Each instance of GitLab CI has an embedded debug tool called Lint. You can find the link under /ci/lint of your gitlab instance. Did you tried ?

Comment: @CristiC777 can you explain little more? Or some link to read about, and how it is related to my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "Production Runner"
  url = "http://gitlab.mydomain.com/ci"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "ubuntu"
    host = "ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX"
    identity_file = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
  [runners.cache]
```

You define

- host
- user
- and identity file

host should be your Build host IP (in other words where you are going to execute your build)
user should be your user on **Build host**. **Not on gitlab host**.

You can test how your password less ssh works by

1. Login to gitlab host as root
2. ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX

If that works and doesn't ask you for a password - all is good.
If that breaks - means you didn't setup password less auth correctly.

The easiest way to setup password less public key based auth is to use command called

```
ssh-copy-id
```

For example I want to setup password less ssh auth between my gitlab and my build host.
My build host ip is 192.168.0.42 and host name is build.home
I already have my id_rsa and id_rsa.pub generated under /home/ubuntu/.ssh on gitlab host.

Now let's push our public key from gitlab host to our build host. First time it will ask you for a password.

```
[root@gitlab ~]# ssh-copy-id -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ubuntu@build.home
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
ubuntu@build.home's password:

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'ubuntu@build.home'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

Note that in above example I was pushing public key to remote host.

But when I will be now connecting to this remote host - I will specify my private key.

```
[root@gitlab ~]# ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@build.home
[ubuntu@build ~]$ hostname
build.home
```

Try testing your public key auth between gitlab host and remote host and update your question.

Resources:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/executors/ssh.md

  P.S: I will post my working environment config a bit later today when I get home.

**Edit 1:**

Here is my config.
My gitlab host is called gitlab.home 192.168.0.41
And I have another VM called sshbuild.home 192.168.0.43

Below is how I added ssh runner

Step 1. Install on my gitlab.home
`yum install gitlab-ci-multi-runner` and register my remote sshbuild.home VM as ssh runner

[image]

[image]

I also need to make sure that password less auth works between my gitlab.home and sshbuild.home, so

```
[root@gitlab gitlab-runner]# ssh-copy-id 192.168.0.43
The authenticity of host '192.168.0.43 (192.168.0.43)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is b4:6a:1b:72:d1:7d:1f:34:f7:bb:ef:ad:69:42:11:13.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
root@192.168.0.43's password:

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh '192.168.0.43'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.

[root@gitlab gitlab-runner]# ssh 192.168.0.43
Last login: Fri Nov 18 17:05:06 2016 from 192.168.0.101
[root@sshbuild ~]# exit
```

Then I disabled my other runner (shell runner) and made new SSH runner project specific just to make sure that when I commit - it will be executed on the ssh runner

[image]

And I do commit and voila - we have our successfull test which was run on sshbuild.home host

[image]

Here is several links which might help with a better understanding of this topic

- https://about.gitlab.com/2016/07/29/the-basics-of-gitlab-ci/
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/README.html
- http://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/README.html
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html

P.S: And here is my /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml file

```
[root@gitlab gitlab-runner]# cat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml 
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "sshbuild"
  url = "http://gitlab.home/"
  token = "2bc1825d8fbde09fd632637c60e9e7"
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "root"
    host = "192.168.0.43"
    port = "22"
    identity_file = "/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
  [runners.cache]
```

P.S: I have similar error as you if I disable HTTP for my repo under Settings in the web interface. However error is not 500 but 403.

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Now I will cover .gitlab-ci.yml based on a simple HelloWorld project
In my HelloWorld I have file called server.js which when run from node - will simply create Web Server running on port 3000 and will reply with "Hello World" on GET requests.

```
 1  const http = require('http');
 2  
 3  const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
 4  const port = 3000;
 5  
 6  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 7    res.statusCode = 200;
 8    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
 9    res.end('Hello World!\n');
10  });
11  
12  server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
13    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
14  });
```

My goal is to be able to run a test case against it. In this case I will run simple

```
curl localhost:3000 | grep "Hello World"
```

But I need to put it into a separate script which will have exit status 0 on success and non zero on failure

```
cat -n simpletest.sh 
     1  #!/bin/bash
     2  
     3  cleanup () 
     4  {
     5   count=`netstat -anp|grep ":3000"|grep LISTEN|awk '{print $NF}'|cut -d\/ -f1|wc -l`
     6   if [ $count -ne 0 ]
     7    then 
     8     pid=`netstat -anp|grep ":3000"|grep LISTEN|awk '{print $NF}'|cut -d\/ -f1`; 
     9     echo "Need to kill PID $pid"; 
    10     kill $pid
    11   fi
    12  }
    13  
    14  echo "Running simple test"
    15  curl localhost:3000|grep "Hello World"
    16  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    17   then
    18    echo "Test was successfull"
    19    echo "Clean up node.js process"
    20    cleanup
    21    exit 0
    22   else
    23    echo "Test failed"
    24    echo "Clean up node.js process"
    25    cleanup
    26    exit 1
    27  fi
```

Now let's cover my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
cat -n .gitlab-ci.yml
     1  test:
     2  
     3    before_script:
     4    - echo "Before script"
     5    - hostname
     6    - /bin/bash cleanup.sh
     7  
     8    script: 
     9    - echo "Main Script"
    10    - node server.js &
    11    - sleep 3
    12    - /bin/bash simpletest.sh
```

I have a single job called test.
In before_script it runs cleanup.sh script which simply kills PID listening on port 3000 in case such found.

```
cat -n cleanup.sh 
     1  #!/bin/bash
     2  count=`netstat -anp|grep ":3000"|grep LISTEN|awk '{print $NF}'|cut -d\/ -f1|wc -l`
     3  if [ $count -ne 0 ]
     4   then 
     5    pid=`netstat -anp|grep ":3000"|grep LISTEN|awk '{print $NF}'|cut -d\/ -f1`; 
     6    echo "Need to kill PID $pid"; 
     7    kill $pid
     8  fi
     9  exit 0
```

And under script: it runs node with my server.js, gives it 3 seconds to start and then runs test against it.
This test will also take care of killing node PID after test is done.

So let's commit and check status of the build

[image]

And now let's change our server.js to output not "Hello World" but "HelloWorld", so there is no space in between. I expect that my test case will fail since it expects literally "Hello World". And it does fail.

[image]

This is the most simplistic CI use case I could come up with.
Now if based on the status of the test case you would like to deploy code to another environment - you would have to start using

- stages
  and
- environment

So your .gitlab-ci.yml would turn into something like this (real working example)

```
cat -n .gitlab-ci.yml
     1  stages:
     2  - test
     3  - deploy
     4  
     5  run_test_case:
     6   stage: test
     7   before_script:
     8   - echo "Before script"
     9   - hostname
    10   - /bin/bash cleanup.sh
    11  
    12   script: 
    13   - echo "Main Script"
    14   - node server.js &
    15   - sleep 3
    16   - /bin/bash simpletest.sh
    17  
    18  deploy_to_production:
    19   stage: deploy
    20   script: 
    21   - echo "Run code here to do production deployment"
    22   environment:
    23    name: production
```

Which upon git push will succeed.
On line 21 I simply ran echo, but this could be replaced with a script which will do push to your remote staging or production environment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about the `gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: One doubt, here in my case both environment are same (gitlab and build on same host), so these steps are not working for me.

Comment: I think I should have a shell runner, tried that and the problem is with cloning as I mentioned in update section of the post. The runner is using `http` to  clone repo and it is not working even in my local system.

Comment: For detailed error and configuration https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24388

Comment: So what's the problem with the same host? You just need to follow same ssh-copy-id approach. It doesn't matter if you are logging into remote or same. But yes, don't use SSH runner if you can. It's better to use SHELL.

Comment: How did you register your runner? If you correctly registered your runner - then it should show up in the Admin Area --> Runners and http clone should work just fine.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying. You should be able to manually check out from http repo and this doesn't work in you case.

Comment: Yeah, I think there is no issue with runner. The problem is http clone not working (changed to shell runner).

Comment: For a separation, I already have a question related to that issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534682/git-clone-with-http-not-working-in-gitlab

Comment: Have you checked in the Settings if you allow both protocols for access to your Git? There is an option to disable HTTP completely and leave only SSH. When I do that - I have similar situation. Builds fail since it can't access my repo via http. However error is not 500 but 403.

Comment: In my ec2 enabled access to all ports from anywhere.

Comment: It's not EC2 setting. It's gitlab GUI setting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128521/discussion-between-dmitry-zayats-and-devo).

Comment: Oh, I don't know that posted almost all configs over these posts.where can I check it? I can see both http and ssh cloning option in my gitlab project.